# RaisePropertyChanged in another view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a main ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MenuViewModel MenuVM { get; set; }
    public StatusBarViewModel StatusBarVM {get; set; }
}
```

each sub-viewmodel has properties binded on a view :

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    private string _property1;
    public  string  Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StatusBarViewModel
{
    private string _property2;
    public  string  Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            _property2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Property2");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Property1");
        } 
    }
}
```

That I want to do, is, when is Property2 is changed, raise property changed in order to update Property1.

So the problem is `Property1.Get` is not called when I change Property2 (I tested with a breakpoint).

The questions are :

Why this is not working ?
 How to do make this work ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to call it for the right view model instance. E.g. `menuViewModelInstance.RaisePropertyChanged("Property1");`

Comment: @Sinatr, it cannot works because MVVMLight handler is null when calling RaisePropertyChanged from another instance of the property. Then it returns without calling the handler. See code : var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember! You can not call `RaisePropertyChanged()` from an instance because the method is protected in MVVM Light! So make a wrapper in your `MenuViewModel`:

```
public void RaiseProperty1Changed()
{
     RaisePropertyChanged("Property1");
}
```

In your `MainViewModel` subscribe to the Event `RaisePropertyChanged` of `Property2` in `StatusBarViewModel`.

```
StatusBarVM.PropertyChanged += OnProperty2Changed
```

And in this delegate method call:

```
private void OnProperty2Changed(object sender, PopertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Property2")
    {
            MenuVM.RaiseProperty1Changed();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MenuViewModel MenuVM { get; set; }
    public StatusBarViewModel StatusBarVM { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MenuVM = new MenuViewModel();
        StatusBarVM = new StatusBarViewModel();

        StatusBarVM.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Property2" && MenuVM != null)
                MenuVM.RaisePropertyChanged("Property1");
        };
    }
}

public class MenuViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _property1;
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
}

public class StatusBarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _property2;
    public string Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            _property2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Property2");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers show nice workarounds, they create however hard references to the ViewModels, or check the name of the property to be change-raised, and I find that too much coupled,I suggest you to use another approach for implementing the StatusBar.

One good approach is to use the `Messenger` Pattern, I've build here a sample library that provides a `StatusBar` UserControl, and a Helper class `StatusManager` that helps the controls inside the StatusBar to `Subsribe` to updates, and that allows external objects to send `updates` to the StatusBar

**Subscription :**

```
public static void Subscribe<TSubscriber, TMessage>(string token, Action<TMessage> subscriberAction)
        {
            _subscribers.Add(new Subscribtion<TSubscriber, TMessage>(subscriberAction, token));
        }
```

**Updating :**

```
public static void UpdateStatus<TSubscriber, TMessage>(object status, string token)
        {
            if (!(status.GetType() == typeof(TMessage)))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Message type is different than the second type argument");
            }

            var subscribersWithCorrespondingType = (from subscriber in _subscribers
                               where (subscriber.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(TSubscriber)) &&
                                      (subscriber.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[1] == typeof(TMessage))
                               select subscriber).ToList();

            var subscribers = (from subscriber in subscribersWithCorrespondingType
                               where ((Subscribtion<TSubscriber, TMessage>) subscriber).Token == token
                               select subscriber).ToList();

            foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
            {
                ((Subscribtion<TSubscriber, TMessage>)subscriber).SubscriberAction((TMessage)status);
            }
        }
```

**Use :**

If the The StatusBar Contains a Label called `lblCursorPosition`, it can subscribe to updates of type `string` :

```
StatusManager.Subscribe<Label, string>((s) =>
            {
                lblCursorPosition.Content = s;
            });
```

and Updating it would look like this :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StatusManager.UpdateStatus<Label, string>("StatusBar's label updated !!"); 
        }
```

As you can see, this provides more independence and flexibility, I'd pleased to receive suggestions and corrections.

Comment: ok good idea. In this case i would use the Messenger in MVVM Light. But whta is so wrong on "create hard references"?

Comment: @SebastianRichter It is not "so wrong", I just find it to be somehow coupled, it's always better to keep your classes (even your viewmodels) decoupled, less coupled code, better software.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to enhance @Sebastian Richter solution to be more generic with the property to notify :

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper to Raise a Property name from outside this View Model
/// It's not possible to call RaisePropertyChanged(..) from outside in MVVM Light.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName"></param>
internal void OuterRaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

Then call it from another Class instance :

```
public class StatusBarViewModel
{
    private string _property2;
    public  string  Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            _property2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Property2));
            OuterRaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MenuVM.Property1));
        } 
    }
}
```

Please note that using `nameof` keyword has the advantage that when you rename the Property name using VS IDE, it will rename all variable names in the solution comprising the RaisePropertyChanged parameters.

@Epitouille, I think that it was what you where searching for.

Regards